# Transformation buttons disappeared

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

I have no idea why but those translate / rotate / scale bottom buttons disappeared and I can't get them back, no matter what edit mode I'm in.

When I create a new file, they appear. when loading my model file - the are absent.

How do I get them back?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First off you have to be in either *Edit mode* or *Object mode* to see the manipulator options, and the [3D manipulator](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/manipulators.html).

If your 3D view header looks like the image below, then you toggled off the 3D manipulator. All you have to do is click the toggle 3D manipulator button (highlighted in red), or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> (which is likely how you disabled it without knowing).

[image: 3D view header with the manipulator button highlighted]

---

The options in the user preferences, Interface tab for the manipulator won't disable it, but if the size is set to the min (10px) it will be very hard to see.

[image: user preferences]

This is the actual size when *Handle Size* and *Size* are set to the min. The image has the 3D cursor as a size reference.
[image: tiny 3D manipulator]