# How do I enable the xyz axis cursor thing when I am in edit mode and moving around the points?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

You know what I am talking about, right? I am following along a video on YouTube and when he clicked on a point, an xyz axis thing popped up on it and it is not doing the same for me. Help?

Comment: Or this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49549/transformation-buttons-disappeared

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the ***3D Manipulator Widget*** enabled:

[image]